# How to use NativeMethods.GetUpdateRect on Mono on Lubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: c#, mono, native-methods

I'm trying to port a great Windows Forms program to Linux and get this error:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetUpdateRect
  at (wrapper managed-to-native)  
CDBurnerXP.Controls.NativeMethods:GetUpdateRectInternal  
(intptr,System.Drawing.Rectangle&,bool)  
at CDBurnerXP.Controls.NativeMethods.GetUpdateRect  
(System.Windows.Forms.Control cntl) [0x0000f] in  
<ce4ca0f630654e4c8c1f96509f1eae82>:0
```

Is there a way to support C# calls to
    NativeMethods:GetUpdateRect  noon Mono on Lubuntu 16.04.1?

---

Edit:
Thanks, knocte, for your comment. This edit is to quote the bit of code that tries to reference this function (because comments don't allow any formatting):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetUpdateRect", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr GetUpdateRectInternal(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle r, bool eraseBackground);
```

Comment: if your Windows Forms program uses native P/Invokes, it's already a non-crossplatform program that depends on Windows system calls

Comment: Thanks, nocte, but I am too new to this scene to be sure I understand you properly. I have added the bit of code that tries to reference GetUpdateRect to my original question, so the code section can be formatted properly.

Comment: Yes, the program was not written with cross-platform use in mind -- only with Windows in mind. So I guess I'm asking if anyone knows if there is anything in mono on Linux that would do what GetUpdateRect does on Windows. Or any table of correlations between functions on Windows and their equivalents on Linux. Thanks again for thinking about these questions. I am persisting because Ketarin is such a useful program and I'd like to be able to run in natively on Linux. (It used to work over WINE, but something has broken, and I have not been able to fix it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is that I was asking the wrong question.
I should have been asking "How can I replace ObjectListView.cs, which depends on non-portable Windows system calls, to port this program to Mono on Linux?"

ObjectListView seems to work very well on Windows, but is not compatible with Linux or Mac systems. There's a very good discussion in the
[ObjectListView discussion board](https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812922/thread/45379c2c/). The comment by Steve Hiner (2015-11-29) changed the direction of my search. Steve's approach is "I already created a proxy that uses OLV on Windows and the stock listview on Linux and Mac. That would be one way OLV could provide pseudo mono support, it could just use the stock listview without any fancy features."

Thanks, knocte, for getting me thinking in the right direction.